# estou com um problema em carregar imagens no meu html

Tags: html

tentei de tudo, ja ativei o java, ja verifiquei o código e ja fui em outros fóruns achar pessoas com o mesmo problema mas todas as soluções que deram certo ou errados pra galera eu tentei e não funcionou.
ex:
esse é o jeito mais simples que eu fiz mas ja editei varias vez[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]es, com aspas ou sem aspas ou tentar aumentar a largura ou comprimento e não funciona
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Comment: boa tarde! Preciso ver o seu código, publique ele

Comment: Não publique código como imagem, código deve ser publicado como texto. Adicione a pergunta a arvore de arquivos e pastas do seu site mostrando claramente onde está a página de html e a imagem a ser exibida por essa página.

Answer (score -1):

Se a sua imagem estiver dentro da pasta "Fotos", você vai precisar adicionar a pasta no src. tente:

```
<img src="./Fotos/galeria-06.jpg"/>
```

Dependendo de onde esteja seu código HTML, você conserta o caminho da pasta.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).